# Поиск полинома в С++

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Создать класс `Frac`(дробные числа) с перегруженными операциями `+ - * /` , а также с возможностью приведения типа `Frac->double`. Должны быть реализованы также `ToString()`, `Equals()`, `==`, `!=`. Вычислить значение полинома в точке. Все коэффициенты и x должны иметь тип `Frac`. Сравнить производительность в случае реализации Frac как класса и как структуры

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <sstream>

struct IComparable
{
    virtual bool Equal(const IComparable&) const = 0;
};

template <typename T>
T gcd(const T& m, const T& n)
{
    return n == 0 ? m : gcd(n, m % n);
}

class Frac : public IComparable
{
    int p, q;

    void reduce()
    {
        int d = gcd(p, q);
        p /= d;
        q /= d;

        if (q < 0)
        {
            q = -q;
            p = -p;
        }
    }

  public:
    Frac(int p = 0, int q = 1) : p(p), q(q)
    {
        if (q == 0) throw std::invalid_argument("Делитель равен 0");

        reduce();
    }

    std::string ToString() const
    {
        std::stringstream s;

        if (q != 1) s << '(';

        if (p > q && p % q)
            s << p / q << ' ' << p % q;
        else
            s << p;

        if (q != 1) s << '/' << q << ')';

        return s.str();
    }

    bool operator==(const Frac& other) const
    {
        return p == other.p && q == other.q;
    }

    bool Frac::operator!=(const Frac& other) const
    {
        return !(*this == other);
    }

    bool Equal(const IComparable& other) const
    {
        const Frac* o = dynamic_cast<const Frac*>(&other);
        return o ? *o == *this : false;
    }

    explicit operator double() const
    {
        return double(p) / q;
    }

    Frac operator ~() const
    {
        return Frac(q, p);
    }
    Frac operator -() const
    {
        return Frac(-p, q);
    }

    Frac& operator +=(const Frac& other)
    {
        p = p * other.q + other.p * q;
        q *= other.q;
        reduce();
        return *this;
    }
    Frac& operator -=(const Frac& other)
    {
        return *this += -other;
    }
    Frac& operator *=(const Frac& other)
    {
        p *= other.p;
        q *= other.q;
        reduce();
        return *this;
    }
    Frac& operator /=(const Frac& other)
    {
        return *this *= ~other;
    }
};

Frac operator+(const Frac& lhs, const Frac& rhs)
{
    return Frac(lhs) += rhs;
}
Frac operator-(const Frac& lhs, const Frac& rhs)
{
    return Frac(lhs) -= rhs;
}
Frac operator*(const Frac& lhs, const Frac& rhs)
{
    return Frac(lhs) *= rhs;
}
Frac operator/(const Frac& lhs, const Frac& rhs)
{
    return Frac(lhs) /= rhs;
}

Frac polynomial(Frac coef[], size_t n, const Frac& x)
{
    if (n == 0) return 0;

    Frac result = coef[n - 1];

    for (size_t i = n - 2; i < n; --i)
    {
        result *= x;
        result += coef[i];
    }

    return result;
}

std::string PolynomialToString(Frac poly[], size_t n)
{
    std::stringstream s;

    for (size_t i = n - 1; i < n; --i)
    {
        if (poly[i] != 0)
        {
            if (poly[i] != 1 || i == 0)
            {
                s << poly[i].ToString();

                if (i > 0)
                    s << '*';
            }

            if (i > 0)
            {
                s << 'x';

                if (i > 1)
                    s << "^" << i;

                s << "+";
            }
        }
    }

    return s.str();
}

int main()
{
    Frac poly[] = { Frac(3, 2), Frac(1, -3), 0, -Frac(2, 7) };
    const size_t n = sizeof poly / sizeof poly[0];
    Frac x(2, 8);
    Frac result = polynomial(poly, n, x);
    std::cout << PolynomialToString(poly, n) << '=' << result.ToString();
    std::cout << '=' << static_cast<double>(result);
    std::cout << " при x=" << x.ToString();
    std::cout << "\n" << (Frac(2, 3) / Frac(2, 3)).ToString();
}
```

Однако при компиляции возникают ошибки:

```
d:\c-+\struct_frac\class_frac\class.cpp(57): error C2071Frac::operator double: недопустимый класс хранения
1>d:\c-+\struct_frac\class_frac\class.cpp(100): error C2666: Frac::operator !=: для 2 перегрузок есть подобные преобразования
1> d:\c-+\struct_frac\class_frac\class.cpp(48): может быть "bool Frac::operator !=(const Frac &) const"
1> или "встроенный оператор C++!=(double, int)"
1> при попытке сопоставить список аргументов "(Frac, int)"
1>d:\c-+\struct_frac\class_frac\class.cpp(101): error C2666: Frac::operator !=: для 2 перегрузок есть подобные преобразования
1> d:\c-+\struct_frac\class_frac\class.cpp(48): может быть "bool Frac::operator !=(const Frac &) const"
1> или "встроенный оператор C++!=(double, int)"
1> при попытке сопоставить список аргументов "(Frac, int)"
```

Comment: Что касается стр. 48 -- лишний описатель Frac:: (внутри описания класса)

Про остальное транслятор g++ 4.6.3 молчит

     g++ a.c++ -std=c++0x

Comment: исправил.но особо ничего не поменялось

Comment: Что за компилятор?

Comment: делаю в Visual Studio 2012

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы заработало в старой версии VC++, нужно убрать `explicit` из

```
explicit operator double() const
```

Но! это автоматически приводит к тому, что при сравнении с `int` получается неоднозначность - сравнивать, преобразуя в `double` или во `Frac`. Так что еще в двух местах нужно исправить -

```
if (poly[i] != 0)
{
    if (poly[i] != 1 || i == 0)
```

на

```
if (poly[i] != Frac(0))
{
    if (poly[i] != Frac(1) || i == 0)
```